# Javascript event from button to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7, phonegap

So i have this buttons:

```
<div class="btndiv" style="margin-top:4vh;">
<button class="btngaleria" onclick="capturePhoto()" style="margin-top:3vh; background-color: #5f919d;"> Camâra </button> 
<button class="btngaleria" onclick="getPhoto()" style="margin-top:3vh; background-color: #5f919d;"> Galeria </button>
<div style="text-align:center;margin:20px;">
<img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:auto;height:120px;"></img>
</div>
<button class="btngaleria" onclick="photoUpload()" style="margin-top:3vh; background-color: #5f919d;"> Enviar </button> 

</div>
```

And i have this functions that gets executed when i click each button:

```
function capturePhoto(){
                    navigator.camera.getPicture(picOnSuccess, picOnFailure, { 
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                        correctOrientation: true
                    });
                }

                function getPhoto(){
                    navigator.camera.getPicture(picOnSuccess, picOnFailure, { 
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                        correctOrientation: true
                    });
                }

function photoUpload() {
                    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                    options.fileKey = "file";
                    options.fileName = sPicData.substr(sPicData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                    options.chunkedMode = false;

                    var params = new Object();
                    params.sitio = id;
                    options.params = params;

                    ft = new FileTransfer();
                    ft.upload(sPicData, "http://pedrofidalgo.pt/bilapoint/upload.php", win, fail, options); 
                }

                function win(){
                    alert("Foto enviada com sucesso, obrigado!");
                }

                function fail(){
                    alert("O envio da foto falhou, tente de novo.");
                }
```

Im working with framework7, so i cant use event bindings on the buttons, i have to put them on the js side, something like this:

```
$$('#buttonClass').on('click', function (e) {
    myApp.alert('Clicked registerButton!');
});
```

I've already read the information about events handlers and action sheet from the framework7 documentation, but i still cant get it to work...

https://framework7.io/docs/action-sheet.html

Im a begginer to javascript, can anyone give me a help please?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using on wrong, you should bind it to something that can listen for clicks and then check if it is on the thing you want. For example:

```
$('body').on('click', '#buttonClass', function(){
    // do something
});
```

I don't know framework7, but if it is a single page application, do not bind stuff to the body because it will stay there, unless you plan to unbind them or clean it up at some point.

Comment: My page is called single.html, but it cant contain javascript. All my javascript related to the single is after the "myApp.onPageInit('single', function (page) { on my js file... So inside this i should put $('single').on('click', '#buttonClass', function(){
    // do something
}); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add id="" to the html element:

```
<a href="#" id="mybutton" class="button">MYBUTTON</a>
```

and in js (don't forget the #):

```
$$('#mybutton').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log("mybutton clicked");
});
```